# How to target specific fields in form with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I want to target the first `input[type="text"]` element in a form and if the form does not contain such an element then target the first `input[type="number"]` element.

How can this be done?

This is what I've got so far:

```
$('input[type=text]:first, input[type=number]:first').focus();
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what happens when you delete the `*:`'s?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think you need `*:`

Comment: i would get rid of the whole `form *:` as well, because `input`s will *always* be in forms

Comment: this is strange, because you're trying to focus two inputs - how come?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I might as well get rid of those `*`. The problem is that the second selector seems to override the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.first()` method.

```
$('form input').filter('[type=text], [type=number]').first().focus();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5aafz/

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($('input[type=text]:first').length) {
    $('input[type=text]:first').focus();
} else {
    $('input[type=number]:first').focus();
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/E3Nke/)**

Answer (score 1):

Man, the behavior of the selectors is like in css, and, in this way, you cannot have a failover selector (if one don't exists, get another).
You'll have to use a if like this:

```
if (!$('form input[type=text]:first').size()){
  $('form input[type=text]:first').focus();
}else{
  $('form input[type=number]:first').focus();
}
```

You can save the selector result to avoid the dom search again in the focus function with something like:

```
first_result = $('form :input[type=text]:first')
```

Comment: You need to remove the '*:' from the selectors.

Answer (score 0):

you may also use :first-of-type.

```
$('input[type="text"]:first-of-type, input[type="number"]:first-of-type').focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are selecting both the first `input[type="text"]` AND `input[type="number"]` elements on the page. that's what the `,` means in your jQuery selector.

What you need to do is check for the `input[type="text"]`. If it doesn't exist then you use the `input[type="number"]`. So you're going to need a conditional statement for this.

**Solution:**

```
var firstInput;

firstInput = $('input[type="text"]:first-child');

if(firstInput.length > 0){
    console.log(firstInput);
}else{
    firstInput = $('input[type="number"]:first-child');
    console.log(firstInput);
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UL6k3/2/